# android volley send and receive in one request

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley, android-recyclerview

I have a query to a mysql database, it asks for all the favorite courses, but first I need to pass the user to it. How could I do that?

file java:

```
public class FavoritosFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyFavoritosRecyclerViewAdapter AdapterFavoritos;
    List<Cursos>cursosList;

    RequestQueue  requestQueue;

    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;

    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public FavoritosFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favoritos_list, container, false);



        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
          recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }


            cursosList=new ArrayList<>();
            ejecutarServicio();

            obtenerCursos();

            //asociamos el adaptador al recyclerview
            AdapterFavoritos=new MyFavoritosRecyclerViewAdapter(cursosList, mListener);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(AdapterFavoritos);

        }
        return view;
    }
    private void ejecutarServicio() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_favo) , new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de registro!"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                final String usuario = "avo";
                params.put("usu_usuario",usuario);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    public void obtenerCursos() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_favo),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Curso");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                boolean add = cursosList.add(
                                        new Cursos(
                                                jsonObject1.getString("id_curso"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("titulo"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("descripcion"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("categoria"),
                                                jsonObject1.getString("imagen")

                                        )
                                );
                            }

                            AdapterFavoritos=new MyFavoritosRecyclerViewAdapter(cursosList, mListener);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(AdapterFavoritos);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        );
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(Cursos item);
    }
}
```

this is my php file.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  include 'conexion.php';

$usu_usuario=$_POST['usu_usuario'];


$miDato='';

$consultado="SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE usu_usuario='".$usu_usuario."'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$consultado);

while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $miDato= $mostrar['id_usuario'];


    }
//  echo $miDato;





  $consulta = " SELECT * FROM curso RIGHT JOIN favoritos ON curso.id_curso=favoritos.id_curso WHERE favoritos.id_usuario='".$miDato."'";

   $resultado=$conexion->query($consulta);

    $datos = array();

    while($resultados = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $datos[] = $resultados;
    }

    //echo json_encode($datos);
    echo json_encode(array("Curso" => $datos));

mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

**here my two files java and php to the database query ..
I'm desperate you know how angry when the code does not understand me hahaha;)**

here my two files java and php to the database query ..
I'm desperate you know how angry when the code does not understand me hahaha;)

what I want is to send the user to the query and volley returns the result, I know how to do it separately but I do not understand how to do that in a single request

Comment: You need to send parameters to your String Request. 
and on the backend api you have to write relevant code. 
here is a Volley Tutorial to follow to get things started on android end. 
https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Could you lend me a hand, it is my first project and I am not very educated, I am already reading about the string string but I am not very clear about it, I would really appreciate it, since in this quarantine it is the way I amuse myself;)

Comment: i will try to write a detailed answer. If you want to send me a chat message by searching my name https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ Thanks.

Comment: I looked for you and you do not appear ... the question is that my code works but I must specify which user I have favorites, because I already know how to send and receive, but since I only make a query pass the user and that volley returns the result. in the same php file, I have two queries, 1. query the user. 2. This goes to the second query looking for your favorite courses.
I have no idea how to do it, and thanks for responding brother.

Comment: then i guess it is more of your backend problem then android side okay it would be great if you could add the backend code and share your database schema for us to help to to the point i need to know if there are multiple tables or single table.

Comment: friend I already uploaded both java and php files, and once again I appreciate it. It is the only thing I need to finish my personal project, I swore to finish a project, and the quarantine is almost over;)

Comment: Thank you and you solve my problem

Comment: Glad i could help. Happy Coding.